# Create table using text file bulk insert that is tab

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server from a text file using bulk insert but I keep getting bulk load data conversion error(truncation). Is there something I'm doing wrong? The top part is how the data is in the text and below is the code.

```
    Medication List NDC Code    Brand Name  Generic Product Name    Route   Description Drug ID Drug Name   Package Size    Unit    Dose    Form    MED Conversion Factor       
5-ARI Medications   00054039513 Dutasteride dutasteride 0.5 mg oral capsule oral    5-ARI Medications   d04788  N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A     
5-ARI Medications   00054039522 Dutasteride dutasteride 0.5 mg oral capsule oral    5-ARI Medications   d04788  N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A 


CREATE TABLE [MHS].[DBO].[NDC_DIRECTORY]
(
[MEDICATION_LIST] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[NDC_CODE] [VARCHAR](11) NOT NULL,
[BRAND_NAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[GENERIC_PRODUCT_NAME] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
[ROUTE] [VARCHAR] (20) NULL,
[DESCRIPTION] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[DRUG_ID] [VARCHAR] (20) NULL,
[DRUG_NAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[PACKAGE_SIZE] [VARCHAR] (20) NULL,
[UNIT] [VARCHAR] (10) NULL,
[DOSE] [VARCHAR] (10) NULL,
[FORM] [VARCHAR] (20) NULL,
[MED_CONVERSION_FACTOR] [VARCHAR] (10) NULL

) ON [PRIMARY];



BULK INSERT MHS.DBO.NDC_DIRECTORY FROM 'C:\SQL\NDC_Directory.txt' 
        WITH (
              FIRSTROW = 2,
              FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
              ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
             );
```

Comment: Do you have better luck when you use `ROWTERMINATOR = 0x0a`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I still get the same message.

Comment: shame, it was a long shot.

Comment: Please post the exact error message. It may tell you the problematic row number. You could simply have one or more rows in your file where some fields are too large to be inserted. That's what truncation means. You have to be sure your file indeed has Linux line endings (`\n`). A regular Windows file will have CRLF as carriage return, that is is `\r\n`. And it goes without saying, the fields should be separated by **tabs**. If you happen to have a **fixed-length** CSV file, the fields wouldbe separated by one or more spaces. Then you might need a **format file**.

Comment: I suggest you extend all columns to VARCHAR(8000), try importing the file. If successful you can go looking through the imported data and find the max length of each field. If you get the same truncation error then there is probably some issue with inconsistent delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sm84  Please check the number of columns in the `NDC_DIRECTORY` table compared to the number of columns in the NDC_Directory.txt file.  It appears that the `NDC_DIRECTORY` tables has 13 total columns.   While the NDC_Directory.txt file has 12 total columns.

When I run the bulk insert with the provided text file, it does result in the following error:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (truncation) for row 2, column 12 (FORM).

When I add an additional column of data to NDC_Directory.txt, the bulk insert completes successfully.

> (2 rows affected)
>    Completion time: 2020-02-21T20:05:15.1860762-06:00

It’s difficult to discern the tab `\t` field separators from the provided sample text input.   My assumption is that “`dutasteride 0.5 mg oral capsule oral`” is all part of the “`Generic Product Name`” attribute.

Comment: Thanks. What is the best way to format? Should I go through the text file and check every line to see if there is an issue in a row?

Comment: There are a couple of approaches to consider.   In general, try to narrow down the problem by reducing the complexity of the import file.   Would suggest to try and get one row to import successfully by initially just having the header row with column names and one row of data.   If that doesn't work, try confirming the number of columns in the header row with the number of delimited columns in the data row.   I added a fictitious column to the end of each row and the import was successful.  Hope that helps!